# I need to convert Eurostat data from wide to long in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to convert from wide to long data from Eurostat, I have the following data frame:
`my_filter_pars = {'startPeriod': 2019,'endPeriod': 2022, 'unit': ['CP_MEUR'], 's_adj': ['NSA'], 'na_item': ['B1GQ', 'P3', 'P6', 'P7', 'D2'], 'geo': ['SE']} data = eurostat.get_data_df(code, filter_pars=my_filter_pars) data`

```
freq    unit    s_adj   na_item geo\TIME_PERIOD 2019-Q1 2019-Q2 2019-Q3 2019-Q4 2020-Q1 ... 2020-Q3 2020-Q4 2021-Q1 2021-Q2 2021-Q3 2021-Q4 2022-Q1 2022-Q2 2022-Q3 2022-Q4
0   Q   CP_MEUR NSA B1GQ    SE  116473.3    121863.5    113869.4    124661.1    117131.8    ... 117367.3    130876.0    125801.4    135425.5    129525.4    147612.1    131761.2    144516.3    136193.4    144892.7
1   Q   CP_MEUR NSA P3  SE  81128.2 85120.0 82939.7 87885.3 81520.2 ... 84735.9 90948.6 86804.5 93820.9 93434.4 101627.2    90085.0 99701.3 96747.2 100465.9
2   Q   CP_MEUR NSA P6  SE  55783.7 58501.8 55460.8 58242.2 55069.0 ... 49752.2 59278.6 57470.3 61642.7 59429.0 70601.9 68847.7 73447.2 71698.8 78980.4
3   Q   CP_MEUR NSA P7  SE  51240.5 52312.9 50687.9 53796.1 49496.1 ... 45162.4 51863.7 51192.7 54630.8 55073.9 64321.9 64498.0 71100.8 70430.4 73475.4
4   Q   CP_MEUR NSA D2  SE  25020.7 26978.0 25362.7 27566.4 24504.9 ... 26289.9 28490.5 26747.2 29536.3 27902.3 32087.6 28119.4 31058.7 28578.8 32500.1


I want the data to show like this:

    na_item      B1GQ        P3       P6       P7       D2
0   2019-Q1  116473.3   81128.2  55783.7  51240.5  25020.7
1   2019-Q2  121863.5   85120.0  58501.8  52312.9  26978.0
2   2019-Q3  113869.4   82939.7  55460.8  50687.9  25362.7
3   2019-Q4  124661.1   87885.3  58242.2  53796.1  27566.4
4   2020-Q1  117131.8   81520.2  55069.0  49496.1  24504.9
5   2020-Q2  115359.3   81340.3  46704.9  42691.4  24406.0
6   2020-Q3  117367.3   84735.9  49752.2  45162.4  26289.9
7   2020-Q4  130876.0   90948.6  59278.6  51863.7  28490.5
8   2021-Q1  125801.4   86804.5  57470.3  51192.7  26747.2
9   2021-Q2  135425.5   93820.9  61642.7  54630.8  29536.3
10  2021-Q3  129525.4   93434.4  59429.0  55073.9  27902.3
11  2021-Q4  147612.1  101627.2  70601.9  64321.9  32087.6
12  2022-Q1  131761.2   90085.0  68847.7  64498.0  28119.4
13  2022-Q2  144516.3   99701.3  73447.2  71100.8  31058.7
14  2022-Q3  136193.4   96747.2  71698.8  70430.4  28578.8
15  2022-Q4  144892.7  100465.9  78980.4  73475.4  32500.1
```

I tried
data = pd.melt(data, id_vars='na_item', value_vars=['2019-Q1', '2022-Q1'],
var_name='time', value_name='millions')

Answer (score 0):

To convert the wide data to long format, you can use the pandas function melt(). Here's an example code:

```
import pandas as pd

# assuming your wide-format data is stored in the variable "data"
long_data = pd.melt(data, id_vars=['geo', 'na_item', 'unit', 's_adj'], var_name='time', value_name='value')
```

In this code, id_vars is a list of columns that should remain as they are, and var_name is the name of the new column that will contain the former column headers. The resulting long_data dataframe will have a row for each combination of geo, na_item, unit, s_adj, and time.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to [`T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html)*ranspose* a portion (*by excluding the Q's*) of your DataFrame:

```
out = (data.set_index(["freq", "unit", "s_adj", "na_item"])
           .T.droplevel([0, 1, 3],  axis=1).reset_index(names="na_item")
           .rename_axis(columns=None)
      )
```

Output :

```
print(out)

    na_item      B1GQ        P3       P6       P7       D2
0   2019-Q1 116473.30  81128.20 55783.70 51240.50 25020.70
1   2019-Q2 121863.50  85120.00 58501.80 52312.90 26978.00
2   2019-Q3 113869.40  82939.70 55460.80 50687.90 25362.70
3   2019-Q4 124661.10  87885.30 58242.20 53796.10 27566.40
4   2020-Q1 117131.80  81520.20 55069.00 49496.10 24504.90
5   2020-Q2 118422.10  83698.60 52053.70 45667.60 21094.30
6   2020-Q3 117367.30  84735.90 49752.20 45162.40 26289.90
7   2020-Q4 130876.00  90948.60 59278.60 51863.70 28490.50
8   2021-Q1 125801.40  86804.50 57470.30 51192.70 26747.20
9   2021-Q2 135425.50  93820.90 61642.70 54630.80 29536.30
10  2021-Q3 129525.40  93434.40 59429.00 55073.90 27902.30
11  2021-Q4 147612.10 101627.20 70601.90 64321.90 32087.60
12  2022-Q1 131761.20  90085.00 68847.70 64498.00 28119.40
13  2022-Q2 144516.30  99701.30 73447.20 71100.80 31058.70
14  2022-Q3 136193.40  96747.20 71698.80 70430.40 28578.80
15  2022-Q4 144892.70 100465.90 78980.40 73475.40 32500.10
```